# mail.info log says sent, but hotmail doesnt receive

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I'm trying to send an email to a @live.com email address and the mail.info log says:

```
Jun  4 19:59:14 bv-webserver postfix/smtp[21205]: 7055311C10B: to=<email@live.com>, relay=mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0/0/0.34/0.76, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <20130604185913.7055311C10B@webserver.domain.com> Queued mail for delivery)
```

So far so good. But when I check my inbox at hotmail, nothing is there. Not even on junk, completely gone.

I've tested with @gmail.com email address and it receives the test email just fine.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The message may be thrown out without notifying sender and recipient. Some (IMHO sub-standard) services do not care about consequences of such policy.

As **the recipient** ask `postmaster@live.com` why you have not received the message.

Comment: Sorry, this may be a stupid question, but what do you mean "ask postermaster@live.com"? Should I just send an e-mail asking why I haven't received my email, or is it an automated system where I have to fomart my email in a specific way?

Comment: I have suggested **standard** contact email. Live.com may prefer another **non standard** contact procedure for question "Why the **wanted** email message accepted by a hotmail server did not reach my mailbox?". I wish you luck: My contacts with abuse@hotmail.com have not created impression of professionalism or good organization.